# Provoke long calls of __aeabi_fxxx functions with GCC on arm cortex

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

I am trying to provoke long calls of __aeabi_fmul function from a foo.c file.
I am not using libgcc, during linking i am passing a symbol file that has the address of __aeabi_fmul.

In foo.c i can see that the compiler assembled the call into the instruction:

```
BL address_of_aeabi_function
```

That's fine, but I would like to provoke a long call where the 32bits address of the function will be in the .got section and the compiler will end up doing the BL using a 32bits register, hence doing the long call.

I am able to provoke long calls on my own functions using the attribute:

```
float my_func(float) __attribute__((long_call));
```

but

```
float __aeabi_fmul(float, float) __attribute__((long_call));
```

does not work ...

I am also able to provoke long calls on __aeabi_fmul if i specify -mlong-calls in the compiler flags
But if i do this, all functions are using long calls, which is not what i want.

Comment: Just a clarification, if you call `__aeabi_fmul(a, b)`, you get a linker error? Or this works but you want long calls to be implicitly used whenever there is a float multiplication?

Comment: Actually calling explicitly __aeabi_fmul(a, b) works, and it also provoke a long call ! However, it does not when i use * in my code and the compiler issues the call to __aeabi_fmul(a, b)  .. it seems in that case it ignores the "long call" attribute

Comment: @BubbleBobble I suppose that's because implementing `*` with a call to that function is an implementation detail independent from any function you declare.

Comment: @fuz yeah that might be it, the compiler is not printing any warning like " warning: implicit declaration of function __aeabi_fmul " so it does find the definition from somewhere internally (?) So there is no way to override that definition whatever that might be ?

Comment: @BubbleBobble I suppose this implementation detail is not handled like a normal function call and thus cannot be overridden or changed in any way.  You might need to look into the compiler source to be sure.

Comment: These functions are intrinsic to the compiler.  Declaring them as 'long_call' will only apply to your code and you don't call these directly.  They are helper function that the compiler uses to do math operations.  If you want the main code bulk, you can use a shim.  Link your `__aeabi_ful` which just does a *long_call* to the code that actually does things.